# Is there a way to disable the snow version of maps?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

When I create a game, sometimes I get a snow version of the map. Instead of having the brown desert land or green grass land, I get a whited out snow covering the land. It's hard to see my units / resources.

Is there a way to disable the snow versions of the maps?

Comment: I guess this is very possible with mod that replaces the textures from snow version to normal version, but I don't if it exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sadly there is not a way to disable snow maps. It seems that the map’s environment is randomly selected when starting each game.